# removing links from string only when exact matches are found

Tags: r

I have some data and I want to remove the character strings which contain `https://someWebsiteLink.com`. However, I only want to remove the stand-alone links.

I tried: `str_remove(links, "https://someWebsiteLink.com")` which removes all of the instances of `https://someWebsiteLink.com`. I also tried to remove the instances only when the number of characters were greater than some value.

```
sapply(strsplit(as.character(urls), "\\s+"), function(x){str_remove(x[nchar(x) >= 8], "https://someWebsiteLink.com")})
```

Which gave me the same result.

Expected output:

```
"https://someWebsiteLink.com/companies/CompanyA"
""
"https://someWebsiteLink.com/companies/CompanyB"
""
```

Data:

```
links <- c("https://someWebsiteLink.com/companies/CompanyA", "https://someWebsiteLink.com", 
"https://someWebsiteLink.com/companies/CompanyB", "https://someWebsiteLink.com"
)
```

Comment: Try `links[nchar(links) < 8|links != 'https://someWebsiteLink.com']`

Comment: Thanks! this does almost what I want. Is there a way I can keep the empty ' ""' links in their current place? This solution removes the ' ""'  empty strings.

Comment: I think this gets what I want `sapply(strsplit(as.character(urls), "\\s+"), function(x){x[nchar(x) < 8|x != "https://myWebsite.com"]}) %>% str_c()` however, I get a warning `argument is not an atomic vector; coercing` - now I want to collapse all of the `character(0)` down to just `""` empty characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use regex when you want to exactly match whole strings. Use `==` or `%in%` for entire string exact matches.

```
links[links == "https://someWebsiteLink.com"] <- ""
links
# [1] "https://someWebsiteLink.com/companies/CompanyA" ""                                              
# [3] "https://someWebsiteLink.com/companies/CompanyB" ""
```

Or

```
ifelse(links == "https://someWebsiteLink.com", "", links)
# [1] "https://someWebsiteLink.com/companies/CompanyA" ""                                              
# [3] "https://someWebsiteLink.com/companies/CompanyB" ""
```

Use regex when you are using its pattern matching capabilities and/or you want to look inside strings, not necessarily at the whole string.

You could do this with regex by using `^` and `$` to anchor the beginning and end of the string:

```
str_replace(links, "^https://someWebsiteLink.com$", "")
# [1] "https://someWebsiteLink.com/companies/CompanyA" ""                                              
# [3] "https://someWebsiteLink.com/companies/CompanyB" ""
```

But this will be less efficient than simply using `==` as above. However, it is more powerful, because you could, for example, match that string whether or not it ends with a `/` (using the `?` quantifier):

```
str_replace(links, "https://someWebsiteLink.com/?$", "")
# [1] "https://someWebsiteLink.com/companies/CompanyA" ""                                              
# [3] "https://someWebsiteLink.com/companies/CompanyB" ""
```

Comment: Yes, your solution is much more elegant than mine! Thanks again! I was missing the `^` and `$` at the beginning and end of the website links.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get some working solution. If somebody has a "nicer" one which doesn't produce a warning message that would be great.

```
links2 <- sapply(strsplit(as.character(links), "\\s+"), function(x){x[nchar(x) < 8|x != "https://someWebsiteLink.com"]}) %>% str_c()
links3 <- lapply(links2, function(x) if(identical(x, "character(0)")) "" else x) %>% str_c()
```

Which gives:

```
[1] "https://someWebsiteLink.com/companies/CompanyA" ""                                               "https://someWebsiteLink.com/companies/CompanyB"
[4] ""
```

Along with this warning message:

> Warning message: In stri_c(..., sep = sep, collapse = collapse,
> ignore_null = TRUE) :   argument is not an atomic vector; coercing